# TreeWalker in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that replaces a phone number with an ahref tag.  In this ahref tag I want to call a javascript function.  To simplify I'm using "javascript:alert('hey')" as the href value.  When I execute the below I get "regs is not defined" for the alert function but for the console.log it displays the correct value.  I tried to append to an existing questions since it's related but someone deleted it and asked that I post a new question.

[Chrome extension, making a link from key words in the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696661/chrome-extension-making-a-link-from-key-words-in-the-body)

```
var re = /(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]??)\s*)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)([2-9]1[02-9]??|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})/
var regs;

var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, function(node) {

if((regs = re.exec(node.textContent))) {

// make sure the text nodes parent doesnt have an attribute we add to know its all ready been highlighted
if(!node.parentNode.classList.contains('highlighted_text')) {
 var match = document.createElement('A');
 match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
 console.log(regs[0]);
 match.href = "javascript:alert(regs[0])";
 console.log(node.nodeValue);

// add an attribute so we know this element is one we added
// Im using a class so you can target it with css easily
match.classList.add('highlighted_text');

var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);

}
}
return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
}, false);



// Make the walker step through the nodes
walker.nextNode();
```

Comment: The `console.log` displays the correct value because it is executed within the context of your extension, the `alert` does not because it is in the context of the page. See [isolated world](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)

Comment: @BeardFist what would be the best way to call a function when the user clicks on the link?  That function must contain the phone number the user clicked.  Obviously building a click-to-dial extension.

Comment: Just use an [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick) handler for it so that it executes within your code.

Comment: I ended up using the onclick but now I'm running into problems using XMLhttpRequest with a different domain than the one its being called from.  Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this working using the following code.

```
match.setAttribute("title", regs[0]);
match.href = "#";
match.addEventListener("click", function(){ make_call('210',this.title); }, false);
```

We then use an XMLHttpRequest that will pass the extension and phone number to an external script that is responsible for making the call.

The only problem we have now is that it doesn't work with phone numbers found in gmail or google maps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the onclick but now I'm running into problems using XMLhttpRequest with a different domain than the one its being called from.  Origin ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here's the code I used for the onclick event:

```
match.setAttribute("onclick", "function make_call(extension, phone) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();xmlhttp.open('GET','http://[Domain]/click2call.php?extension='+extension+'&phone='+phone,false); xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); xmlhttp.send(null); } ; make_call('210','"+regs[0]+"'); return false; ");
```

I'm going to see about using addEventListener instead of using the above method.

Comment: You need to add [host permissions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) for domain you are trying to get.