# Create hyperlinks on certain words in Gmail message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension for Chrome. I wish to create hyperlinks 1) for every certain words (using RegExp), 2) automatically (before display), 3) in gMail message.

However, below codes doesn't work and gmail cannot load its message. Could you let me know why it happened and how I can fix it?

**1.manifest.json**

```
{
    ...
    "content_scripts": [ {
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": true
    } ]
    ...
}
```

**2.content.js**

```
var doFilter = function(elem) {
    //ID Moderators & URL parameters
    var internalID = new RegExp(/[1-9]\d{7,8}/g);
    var internalURL = 'https://mywebsite.com/go?customerId=';

    //Create Hyperlinks for Internal ID
    var internalMatch = elem.innerHTML.match(InternalID);
    for (var i=0; i<internalMatch.length; i++) {
        elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(internalMatch[i], '<a href="' + internalURL + internalMatch[i] + '">' + internalMatch[i] + '</a>');
    }

};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    doFilter(document.body);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension, making a link from key words in the body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696661/chrome-extension-making-a-link-from-key-words-in-the-body)